# How can I stop an auto-generated Linq to SQL class from loading ALL data?

Tags: visual-studio, linq, linq-to-sql, mv

**DUPLICATE of [How can I stop an auto-generated Linq to SQL class from loading ALL data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433422/how-can-i-stop-an-auto-generated-linq-to-sql-class-from-loading-all-data)
post answers there!**

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, much like the [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) tutorial example. (I'm using MVC 2, but followed the NerdDinner tutorial in order to create it).

As per the instructions in [part 3](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm) of the tutorial, I've created a Linq-to-SQL model of my database by creating a "Linq to SQL Classes" (.dbml) surface, and dropping my database tables onto it. The designer has automatically added relationships between the generated classes based on my database tables.

Let's say that my classes are as per the NerdDinner example, so I have Dinner and RSVP tables, where each Dinner record is associated with many RSVP records - hence in the generated classes, the Dinner object has a RSVPs property which is a list of RSVP objects.

**My problem is this**: it *appears* (and I'd be gladly proved wrong on this) that as soon as I 
access a Dinner object, it's loading all of the corresponding RSVP objects, even if I don't use the RSVPs member.

**First question**: is this really the default behavior for the generated classes?

In my particular situation, the object graph contains many more tables (which have an order of magnitude more records), and so this is disastrous behaviour - I'd be loading tons of data when all I want to do is show the details of a single parent record.

**Second question**: are there any properties exposed through the designer UI that would let me modify this behavior? (I can't find any).

**Third question**: I've seen a description of how to control the loading of related records in a `DataContext` by using a `DataShape` object associated with the DataContext. Is that what I'm meant to do, and if so are there any tutorials like the NerdDinner one that would show not only how to do it, but also suggest a 'pattern' for normal use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Dinner class, it doesn't automatically load foreign key relationship properties.  You have to setup data load options for that to work, as in:

```
var o = new DataLoadOptions();
o.LoadWith<Dinner>(i => i.RSVPs);
```

However, anytime you access RSVPs, it will automatically load these by default (and if you navigate to the property in intellisense too, FYI).

HTH.